# Creating Multiple Informix Servers in Setnet32

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, informix

New to SSIS.
Database info:

- Source DB: Multiple Informix servers that run the same application hence the same Informix database name across all these servers.
- Destination DB: Single SQL
- Requirement:
  Extract data from all source Informix servers and import to SQL
- Challenge:
  Installed Informix SDK on SQL and running Setnet32 to setup IBM Informix Server. Setnet32 defines server entry by Informix Server "instance name". This creates a problem because all of my source databases are using the same "instance name" and cannot be changed, and therefore there is ONLY one Server entry in Setnet32. Subsequently, only a single ODBC can be created for the specific Informix server.

**Question:**

- Since I am new to SSIS, I feel I did something fundamentally wrong. What is the correct solution here?

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert, but … On Unix, you could configure each server on each of the source machines with the same server name ('instance name'), but also give each one a unique server alias via DBSERVERALIASES.  You could then arrange that the destination setup connects to the server aliases, while leaving whatever programs populate the source servers to use the same name everywhere. So, for example, the instances might all be called 'ix_production' as the primary server name, but you might have server aliases 'ix_production_01', 'ix_production_02', ... as well, one such alias per machine.

Comment: This does involve a non-damaging minor change in the source machine configurations.  Your ODBC connections setup via SETNET32 would then refer to the aliases.  I think a technique along these lines is a reasonable bet.  In future, I'd recommend setting each instance with a unique name — and ensuring that the applications can connect to servers with arbitrary names rather than a single fixed name.  I dunno if you did the setup with the same name on each machine, but whoever did that arguably made a mistake when they did so.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler, I will check the source server and see if this is possible on Windows server and also if it is supported by the application vendor. The Informix database is installed along with application installation.

Comment: Good luck with the ISV.  Just in case it isn't clear, DBSERVERALIASES is one of the many parameters that can be set in the $ONCONFIG file.  The aliases would need to appear in the Windows equivalent of the 'sqlhosts' file (`$INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts` on Unix — not sure whether SETNET32 subsumes this role on Windows), so that you can specify that `ix_production_01` is on `app-server-01.subdomain.example.com` while `ix_production_02` is on `appserver-02.subdomain.example.com`, etc.  That's the general idea.

Comment: The Informix ODBC driver supports DSN-less connections. There is no need to define Informix servers within the registry (setnet32), you just specify all the details in the connection string. Something like 'DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER};SRVR=dubi1170fc3;DB=stores7;UID=informix;PWD=ximrofni;DLOC=en_US.819;CLOC=en_us.819;SERV=9095;PRO=onsoctcp;HOST=irk"'
This way you can have the same INFORMIXSERVER but different hosts/port. 
I think that is not an option with OLEDB provider, but you should be able to use ODBC from SSIS (with the MS OleDB for ODBC provider bridge)